# Android Emulator: Fake Camera for testing

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to make an application that uses the android camera, but I want to test it using the emulator. I don't have a webcam to use for live image, so I want to know if I can do it faking  a still image (somehow) or I will need to use something like a fake cam on my desktop pc, and then make it be used by the android emulator.

I searched about some solutions but they appears old. Anyone is using something like that and can point me to a "fresh" solution?

Comment: in 4.0 emulator there is a camera for testing..

Comment: ok but this will not work for devices with previous versions, right?